# QtWebEngineProcess immediately closed after start

Tags: qt, qtwebengine, qtwebchannel

I have writed a *Hellow World* program using **QtWebEngineView**:

```
QWebEngineView *web = new QWebEngineView(this);
ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(web);
web->setUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
web->show();
```

The program works as I expected, The problem is that when I deploy this app with **macdeployqt**, It immediately be closed after execute.
I tested the app on **Qt 5.14** & **Qt 5.15** and both have the same problem.
It seems the reason of problem is that **QtWebEngineProcess** be closed automatically after run.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
I'm getting the following error in the console, repeated over and over.
*`ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(262)] Network service crashed, restarting service.`*

Comment: by "after run" you mean "after start", right?

Comment: Is it that you run your app successfully from Qt Creator? Then you create deployable app bundle with macdeployqt, and when you run your app from the bundle it crashes? In that case I recommend you to test your bundle creation and running with actual "hello world" app, i.e. without webengine dependency. After that you try to figure out what libs/plugins are missing from the bundle of the webengine version. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/macos-deployment.html